# Formatting Excel Data as Table from Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am attempting unsuccessfully to format data in Excel as a table from Access.  I was hoping someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong:

First way:

```
    Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    appExcel.Visible = False
    appExcel.Workbooks.Open (strFileName)
appExcel.Workbooks(1).Sheets(lngSheet).ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A1:O6"), , xlYes).Name = _
                "Table1"
    appExcel.Workbooks(1).Sheets(lngSheet).ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium1"
```

Second Way:

```
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    appExcel.Visible = False
    appExcel.Workbooks.Open (strFileName)

    Set wb = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFileName)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$O$6"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table2"

    ws.ListObjects("Table2").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium15"
```

Third Way:

```
Dim wb As Object
    Dim ws As Object
Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    appExcel.Visible = False
    appExcel.Workbooks.Open (strFileName)

    Set wb = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFileName)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$O$6"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table2"

    ws.ListObjects("Table2").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium15"
```

I appreciate any assistance.  Thanks!

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. Is your intent to export a table from Access into an Excel workbook? Or are you trying to make changes to an existing worksheet? Or what? Please be as clear as possible.

Comment: I exported the reports out of Access into Excel.  Then, I opened the Excel reports and formatted them appropriately.  I already got the answer to my question though.  Something was wrong with my range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My range was wrong.  Fixed the range and it works.